# Can I use a function pointer in a trait to call a member function on a struct

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and was playing with traits.

In this example, I'm getting the following error:

```rust
trait HasArea {
    fn area(&self) -> f64;
}

type FPTR = fn() -> f64;
trait MyTrait {
    fn hof_test(&self, func: FPTR) -> FPTR {
        func
    }
}

struct Square {
    side: f64,
}
impl HasArea for Square {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        self.side * self.side
    }
}

impl MyTrait for Square {}

fn main() {
    let sq = Square { side: 6.2 };

    let area = sq.hof_test(sq.area)();
}
```

The Error is:

```
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `area` on type `Square`
  --> src/main.rs:26:31
   |
26 |     let area = sq.hof_test(sq.area)();
   |                               ^^^^ help: use parentheses to call the method: `area()`
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=20ddad7e4aef8a3575ac44e33cc0b1b3)

Is there a way of calling the `Square.area()` like this?

Comment: How could a function taking &self as argument be use like a function taking zero argument ?

Comment: Anyway, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f766adc62ae2ba8cae84db04b63b3d0c) help you ?

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks. The FnMut() -> f64 thing is fine, I did those. I was trying to do it using a fn pointer. But as you pointed out fn (&self) and fn() are not the same... Thanks anyway

Comment: What I was looking for the correct signature of the fn ptr that should be able to call the area function. Keeping that hof_test0 returns a fn ptr. Thanks

Comment: how about this ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=64dde0cae450bf851437af24466a7a9d

Comment: @ÖmerErden Aha! That's it! I was trying with FPTR = fn(s: Square) -> f64 ... that was wrong. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Prana you're welcome ^^,  `fn(&Square) -> f64;` is still valid, but using generics type parameter is a better idea , otherwise `MyTrait` would be strictly dependent to the `Square`.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Absolutely!... got that.. Thanks again for pointing it out. Best.